# Left invariance of differential form on the circle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, pullback

This is a problem that came up in L. Tu's book An Introduction to Manifolds.

17.3 (Pullback of a 1-form on $S^1$)
Multiplication in $S^1$ viewed as a subset of the complex plane is given by
$$(\cos t+i\sin t)(x+iy)=(x\cos t-y\sin t)+i(x\sin t + y\cos t)$$
Hence if $g=(\cos t,\sin t)\in S^1\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ then left multiplication is given by
$$l_g(x,y)=(x\cos t-y\sin t,x\sin t + y\cos t)$$
Let $\omega=-ydx+xdy$ be a 1-form. Prove
$$l^\ast_g\omega=\omega$$
I did the following computation
$$l^\ast_g\omega=l^\ast_g(-ydx+xdy)=-(l^\ast_g y)(dl^\ast_gx)+(l^\ast_gx)(dl^\ast_gy)$$
which one gets by the linearity, distributivity and commutativity (with $d$) of the pullback $l^\ast_g$.

Since for a function $l^\ast_g f = f \circ l_g$ we can replace the above and apply the differential to obtain the following
$$l^\ast_g\omega = dt + \omega$$
As you can see there is a $dt$ term which I don't know how to get rid of or if it even is supposed to be there. My exact calculation is as follows
\begin{align}
l^\ast_g\omega 
&= -(y\circ l_g)d(x\circ l_g)+(x\circ l_g)d(y\circ l_g)\\
&=-(x\sin t + y\cos t)d(x\cos t-y\sin t)+(x\cos t-y\sin t)d(x\sin t + y\cos t)\\
&=-(\cdots)(-x\sin t dt +\cos t dt dx -y\cos t dt -\sin t dy)\\
&\qquad \qquad+(\cdots)(x\cos t dt +\sin t dx -y\sin t dt+\cos t dy)\\
&=x^2dt-ydx+y^2dt+xdy\\
&=\omega + dt
\end{align}
Since $x^2+y^2=1$ on the circle. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No $dt$ — you are doing the pullback by one fixed group element at a time, so $t$ is fixed.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense! Thank you for your answer and your great book that I've also been reading!